# Mac OS X DNS issue

Tags: macos, dns, server.app

I'm stuck back on Sierra because later OS X Server versions no longer include DNS.

The Server app is a bit limited and doesn't allow you to enter wildcards (perfectly acceptable in BIND which is what is running).

So I edit the NAMED records directly and enter the * records. Works fine, for a while.

Intermittently some process is overwriting the DNS records and removing the wildcard entries.

What is the proper way to adjust records so they don’t revert or have to be repeated manually?

Comment: Can't you just turn disable DNS/BIND in Server.app and run it manually?

Comment: I could but I need to manage about 100 other zones and the GUI is so simple. Would be like throwing out the baby with the bath water.

Comment: I'm currently trying locking the zone record. Will see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Can you give an example of how you want to use the asterisk wildcard?

Comment: *.kindwine.com.au.          10800 IN CNAME kindwine.com.au.